# Type converter for Room Database not working on class which has object from another class

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, converters

I have the following class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "dutyday_table")
data class DutyDay(
@PrimaryKey
val date: Date,
val showTime: Time,
val  closingTime:Time
)
```

and another class which uses objects from class "DutyDay":

```
@Entity(tableName = "tour_table")
data class Tour(
@PrimaryKey
val day1: DutyDay?,
val day2: DutyDay?,
val day3: DutyDay?,
val day4: DutyDay?,
val day5: DutyDay?,
val day6: DutyDay?,
val day7: DutyDay?,
val totalHours: Time
)
```

and the following converter:

```
class Converters {
@TypeConverter
fun longToDate(value: Long?): Date? {
    return value?.let { Date(it) }
}

@TypeConverter
fun dateToLong(date: Date?): Long? {
    return date?.time
}

@TypeConverter
fun longToTime(value: Long?): Time? {
    return value?.let { Time(it) }
}

@TypeConverter
fun timeToLong(date: Time?): Long? {
    return date?.time
}
}
```

The converter is properly annotated in the database, I have used Room Database and converters before they normaly work fine. But with this example Android Studio is complaining that it cannot figure out how to store the fields from class "Tour", I guess because it uses the DutyDays created in class "DutyDay".  Do I somehow have to create another converter for the properties in "Tour"?

Thanks for your help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 objects in your entities that are unknown for Room - `Date`, `Time`, `DutyDay`. You've described TypeConverter just for `Date` and `Time`, so the problem is that Room doesn't know how to persist `DutyDay`.

I think you choices are:

1. Add one more converter for `DutyDay` (to use Gson-converting to string, for example. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52009040/12718414) is link with similar decision).
2. To use foreign keys inside `Tour` table instead of `DutyDay`'s references.