# Type converter for Room database not working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Im trying to apply my converters to room model and after many tries it still gives me

```
    private java.util.List<pl.beskidmedia.bm.tv.retrofit.EpgShort> epg;
                                                                   ^C:\...\bm\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\pl\beskidmedia\bm\tv\cache\Channels.java:21: error: Cannot figure out how to read this field from a cursor.
    private java.util.List<pl.beskidmedia.bm.tv.retrofit.EpgShort> epg;
                                                                   ^
```

Im trying to convert list to string to save it to a database and to achive it im using this

```
class TypeConverters {
    companion object {
        @TypeConverter
        @JvmStatic
        fun toList(string: String?): List<EpgShort>? {
            val listType = object : TypeToken<List<EpgShort>>() {}.type
            return if (string != null) {
                Gson().fromJson<List<EpgShort>>(string, listType)
            } else
                null
        }

        @TypeConverter
        @JvmStatic
        fun fromList(list: List<EpgShort>?): String? {
            val type = object : TypeToken<List<EpgShort>>() {}.type
            return if (list != null) {
                Gson().toJson(list, type)
            } else {
                null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my entity

```
@Entity
data class Channels(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false) val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val number: Int,
    val cmd: String,
    val logo: String,
    val allowPvr: Int,
    val lastUpdate: Long,
    @field:TypeConverters(pl.beskidmedia.bm.tv.cache.TypeConverters::class)
    var epg: List<EpgShort>
)
```

The database itself was working before i added this secound table so I thing it should be just it.

Comment: Did you declare the TypeConverters on your database as per this answer?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52009040/764624

Comment: @IvanWooll yup, i tried to declare it in database alone, in entity alone and in both at the same time, nothing seems to work

Comment: Have you tried converting your `TypeConverters` class to an `object` and get rid of all `@JvmStatic` and `companion object`s?

Comment: Your `epg: List<EpgShort>` is not nullable but your TypeConverter converts nullable types. Have a look at that

Comment: @IvanWooll I added nullable thing after a couple of tries, it wasn't before and I checked it to be sure but still no progress

Comment: @Sdghasemi it was an object before but i saw tutorial somewhere that it was like this so in short i tried this aproach

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the bug, everything was fine but I imported similar named class from different package by mistake, ty for all clues and comments and sorry for this mistake.